# Why is git refusing to discard file changes?

Tags: git

Here's a sample session:

```
PS C:\...\ReactiveUI> git status
On branch rxui7-master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/rxui7-master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   ReactiveUI.Tests/ObservableAsPropertyHelperTest.cs
        modified:   ReactiveUI/Interfaces.cs
        modified:   ReactiveUI/ObservableAsPropertyHelper.cs
        modified:   ReactiveUI/PropertyBinding.cs
        modified:   ReactiveUI/ReactiveUI_WinRT80.csproj
        modified:   ReactiveUI/ViewLocator.cs
        modified:   ReactiveUI/Xaml/Attributes.cs

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
PS C:\...\ReactiveUI> git checkout -- ReactiveUI/Interfaces.cs
PS C:\...\ReactiveUI> git status
On branch rxui7-master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/rxui7-master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   ReactiveUI.Tests/ObservableAsPropertyHelperTest.cs
        modified:   ReactiveUI/Interfaces.cs
        modified:   ReactiveUI/ObservableAsPropertyHelper.cs
        modified:   ReactiveUI/PropertyBinding.cs
        modified:   ReactiveUI/ReactiveUI_WinRT80.csproj
        modified:   ReactiveUI/ViewLocator.cs
        modified:   ReactiveUI/Xaml/Attributes.cs

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
PS C:\...\ReactiveUI>
```

As you can see, git is refusing to throw away file changes. Why?

Comment: What about `git checkout HEAD -- ReactiveUI/Interfaces.cs`?

Comment: @Matt: same result: no error output, but file is still modified

Comment: There are two ways that I know can make this happen, one is end-of-line settings on Windows (I've never had to deal with that) and the other occurs on case-insensitive file systems, including MacOS.  With the case-insensitive file systems it happens when git has two files with names differing *only* in cases (upper/lower).  The easy fix is to rename the file(s) on a case-sensitive system to avoid the clash, check that in, and only then deal with it on the case-insensitive system.